# Scikit-learn Normalization mode (L1 vs L2 & Max)

Tags: normalization, scikit-learn

I was wondering if anyone here can explain the difference between the $L1$, $L2$ and $Max$ normalization mode in `sklearn.preprocessing.normalize()` module?

Having read the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.normalize.html), I couldn't realize the difference!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The options lead to different normalizations. if $x$ is the vector of covariates of length $n$, and say that the normalized vector is $y = x / z$ then the three options denote what to use for $z$:

- L1: $z = \| x\|_1 = \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|$
- L2: $z = \| x\|_2 = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}$
- Max: $z = \|x \|_\infty = \max |x_i|$

Edit: previously, using `Max` does not take absolute values first, so it is not equal to the $l_\infty$ norm -- however, that seems to have been updated and now it is equal to the infinity norm

([source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/51a765a/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py#L1295))

Comment: If Max does not take absolute values first, would you get strange results when all the $x_i$ are negative, or worse if one or more were 0 and the rest negative?