# Use cases of L1, L2 and Max normalisation of a vector

Tags: normalization, norm

I have a vector; and I can normalize it by dividing with either:

- Max of the values of the vector
- L1 norm of the vector
- L2 norm of the vector

The math behind each of the above approaches is nicely given in the following cross validated post for your reference ( [Scikit-learn Normalization mode (L1 vs L2 & Max)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/225564/scikit-learn-normalization-mode-l1-vs-l2-max/564443?noredirect=1#comment1039366_564443) )

However, my question is, what determines if I should use one over the other when normalising vectors? The best I see, all of them ensure relative scales of the elements within the vector are maintained, albeit with different stretch/values. Could you please provide some use-cases of choosing one over the other for "vector normalization vis-a-vis max,L1,L2 norms"?

Thanks,